# iPad application mail sending

Tags: email, ipad, installation

Hee

Does anybody know how to check in-application if a mail account is setup on the device?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can call `[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) to check if there's any mail accounts available *for sending mail*.

Comment: Note that this won't tell you if the device is too old to send mail.